# how to ignore \r\n in regex patterns

Tags: php, regex

After writing this regex pattern to detect links i recognized that sometimes `\r\n` gives me something like this `nhttp://address.com`.

```
$string = "Hello world. http://address.com\r\nhttp://address.com http://www.google.com";
preg_match_all('/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/', $string, $matches);
```

How to ignore `\r\n` if it exists before some links?

Comment: see the docs for `m` in http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @Sammitch How does the `m` factor into the `\n` with the subject string? I thought the `m` just affected the way the `^` and `$` worked of the regex.

Comment: Can you please provide `$string` so we can replicate the issue? You also are over escaping. You could just have `([\w]+://[\w-?&;#~=./@]+[\w/])` or `([\w]+:\/{2}[\w-?&;#~=./@]+[\w\/])` if you didn't want to change the delimiter.

Comment: @user3783243 I added $string to the question.

Comment: Just explode with `\r\n` - http://rextester.com/FPNHA37681

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `\r\n` See the string again. `\r\n` is not always there and unpredictable.

Comment: Cool, use [`preg_match_all("~https?://\S+~i", $string, $m);`](http://rextester.com/XTWRDK17324)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Am I wrong about the `m`, or how does it affect the search string?

Comment: @user3783243 `m` is a MULTILINE modifier that, in PCRE (and .NET, Java, Python, etc. except Ruby), only makes `^` match start of lines and `$` end of lines. In Ruby, it makes `.` match a newline.

Comment: Does `preg_match_all("~https?://\S+~i", $string, $m);` work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah it work, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
preg_match_all("~https?://\S+~i", $string, $m);
```

This matches `http` or `https` then `://`, then 1+ non-whitespace chars.